# Некорректно выводит результат вычисления n-го ряда Фибоначчи

Tags: python

```
number1 = 1
number2 = 1
 
n = int(input("Номер элемента: "))
 
i = 0

while i < n - 2:
    summa = number1 + number2
    number2 = number2
    number2 = summa
    i = i + 1
 
print("Значение элемента:", number2)
```

Не понимаю в чём проблема, писал функцию нахождения, но результат неправильный.

Например, ввожу: `55`
Выводит: `54`, а должно: `139583862445`

Comment: Опечатка при переприсваивании: `number1 = number2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вместо `number1` поставили `number2`

Вот ваш код который исправлен:

```
number1 = 1
number2 = 1
 
n = int(input("Номер элемента: "))
 
i = 0

while i < n - 2:
    summa = number1 + number2
    number1 = number2
    number2 = summa
    i = i + 1
 
print("Значение элемента:", number2)
```